# Operation preserving log-concavity of sequences

Tags: co.combinatorics, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, unimodality

Here a *log-concave sequence* $(a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ is a sequence of positive real numbers such that $a_i^2 \geq a_{i-1}a_{i+1}$ for each $i\geq 1$. These are pervasive within mathematics.

A polynomial $p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^d a_i x^d$ is said to be *log-concave* if the sequence $(a_0,\ldots,a_d)$ of its coefficients is log-concave. We say that $p(x)$ is *unimodal* if there exists some index $j$ such that $a_0\leq \cdots\leq a_{j-1}\leq a_j\geq a_{j+1}\geq \cdots \geq a_d$. The following chain of implications is well known:
$$ p(x) \text{ has only negative real roots} \Longrightarrow p(x)\text{ is log-concave} \Longrightarrow p(x) \text{ is unimodal}.$$

It is known that the usual product of polynomials has the following behavior:

- $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are negative real-rooted $\Longrightarrow$ $p(x)q(x)$ is negative real-rooted.
- $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are log-cocave $\Longrightarrow$ $p(x)q(x)$ is log-concave.
- $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are unimodal does not necessarily imply that $p(x)q(x)$ is unimodal.

(The first one is trivial, and for a proof of the second and an example for the third one can look at [Stanley's survey](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/pubs/pubfiles/72.pdf) on unimodality and log-concavity in combinatorics). Here I am interested in obtaining analogous statements for a slightly more complicated notion of ``product'' of polynomials.

We define the (non-linear) operator $\mathscr{W}:\mathbb{R}[x]\to \mathbb{R}[x]$, that maps $f(x)\mapsto (\mathscr{W}f)(x)$, where $\mathscr{W}f$ is the only polynomial of degree $\leq \deg f(x)$ satisfying:
$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} f(m) x^m = \frac{(\mathscr{W}f)(x)}{(1-x)^{1+\deg f(x)}}.$$
(This operator appears quite frequently in Ehrhart theory, combinatorics, commutative algebra, etc.)

In his PhD Thesis, David Wagner proved the following result (it corresponds to Theorem 0.3 in his paper [*Total positivity of Hadamard products*](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-247X(92)90261-B))

**Theorem:** If $f$ and $g$ are polynomials such that $\mathscr{W}f$ and $\mathscr{W}g$ are negative real-rooted, then $\mathscr{W}(fg)$ is negative real-rooted too.

This is a quite important result in the theory of Pólya frequency sequences. It has many consequences in combinatorics, such as the validity of the Neggers-Stanley conjecture for certain classes of posets (though it fails for posets in general). My questions are the following:

**Question 1:** If $f$ and $g$ are polynomials such that $\mathscr{W}f$ and $\mathscr{W}g$ have positive coefficients and are log-concave, is it true that $\mathscr{W}(fg)$ is log-concave too?

**Question 2:** If $f$ and $g$ are polynomials such that $\mathscr{W}f$ and $\mathscr{W}g$ have positive coefficients and are unimodal, is it true that $\mathscr{W}(fg)$ is unimodal too?

My intuition is that the answer to the first question should be affirmative, and the answer to the second should be negative (of course, I haven't been able to produce any counterexamples). Unfortunately, the ideas in Wagner's proof for real-rootedness do not carry straightforwardly to the case of log-concavity.

Comment: What about palindromic and $\gamma$-nonnegative?

Comment: @SamHopkins A hint in that direction would be appreciated as well!

Answer (score 2):

If my calculations are correct, a counterexample for question 2 is $$f= \frac{720 + 1684x + 1350x^2 + 585x^3 + 90x^4 + 11x^5}{120} \\
g = \frac{600 + 1434x + 1175x^2 + 535x^3 + 85x^4 + 11x^5}{120}$$ having $$\mathscr{W}f= 6 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 \\
\mathscr{W}g = 5 + 2x+ x^2+ x^3 + x^4 + x^5 \\
\mathscr{W}(fg)= 30 + 854x + 4320x^2 + 7292x^3 + \color{red}{7194}x^4 + 7442x^5 + 2059x^6 + 962x^7 + 300x^8 + 38^9 + x^{10}$$

---

To Sam Hopkins' suggestions in comments, a counterexample for palindromes is $$f = 2 + 4x + 3x^2 + x^3 \\
g = 2 + 3x + 3x^2 \\
\mathscr{W}f = \mathscr{W}g = 2 + 2x + 2x^2 \\
\mathscr{W}(fg) = 4 + 56x + 180x^2 + 104x^3 + 16x^4$$

And a counter-example for $\gamma$-non-negative is $$f = \frac{6 + 16x + 15x^2 + 5x^3}6 \\
g = \frac{2 + 5x + 5x^2}2 \\
\mathscr{W}f = \mathscr{W}g = 1 + 3x + x^2 \\
\mathscr{W}(fg) = 1 + 36x + 131x^2 + 76x^3 + 6x^4$$

Comment: I have checked and your examples are correct! Thank you.

Comment: @LuisFerroni, my search program finds these in 8 seconds for unimodal and negligible time for palindrome and $\gamma$-non-negative. It's been running for over 2 hours without finding a counterexample for log-concave, so that's some empirical support for your intuition.